# Importing data in excel from web page

Tags: excel

I want import data from this Web page (www.psx.com.pk) into my excel sheet . It is a stock exchange website and I want to download daily stock quotes into my excel sheet.

There is a tab named market summary when I press that tab I don't get the url for that data .

Please help me in importing market summary data in my excel sheet.

Note that the data in market summary updates every 5 minutes when the market is open that is from ( 9:30 am to 3:30 pm pakistan standard time GMT+5) After market closes the data stays there .

Answer (score 0):

You need acces to their databases or API. if i understand what you want correctly